# Simple htaccess url forwarding not working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to forward all PDF requests made to http://files.domain.com through an index.php file I've built on my server.  First I just need a test.  So I put together this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule file2.pdf index.php [R]
```

When I go to that URL it doesn't show my index.php but only a 404 error.  I'm not sure what's up... any suggestions?

I've verified that my .htaccess and index.php are in the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my virtual host has `AllowOverride` set to `NONE`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride